# Giving a dog a bigger capsule -or can I break open and mix a mulitvitamin with food

Tags: dogs, medicines

My dog's generally pretty good about being pilled. However, with bigger pills, he tends to chew, and in the case of the multivitamin he's getting (sangobion), results in a fair amount of the powder in the capsule bursting and getting all over his beard.

Its not very efficient, and its too big for him to swallow comfortably anyway.

I know generally with medicines, its not a good idea to crush it up - but this is basically an iron suppliment. Is there any better way to give it to him?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things we'd do with reluctant dogs and regular medications is either mix it with some wet dog food or some low-fat salad dressing. It's easy to break the capsule open and hard pills can be stuck in a small piece of aluminum foil or plastic wrap and tap it with a hammer till it's powder. I used to keep a plastic spoon. I'd put the powder on it, and a spoon worth of low-fat honey mustard dressing, and my lab would suck down her joint supplements with no problems.

Answer (score 0):

I inserted the capsule inside a piece of chicken liver and gave him a few bits of plain liver before giving him the liver with the capsule.